# Many PCs, one PSU?

Tags: power-supply

I am in need to build many computers and I must keep the cost low. I can buy cheap 15$ psu, but i really fear about fires/explosions.

Is it possible to buy a big, pricey psu and connect say 3 or 4 pcs there?

The computers will have only 2 connectors:

24-pin ATX main power connector
4-pin ATX 12V

and nothing more (no hdd, no nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one manufactures such a power supply, as far as I'm aware; a Google search finds only people asking the same question you are, none of whom seems to have received an answer in the affirmative. You would therefore, at the very least, need to:

- Find a PSU capable of putting sufficient amperage on its motherboard supply lines to stably power more than one motherboard. (This is *not* the same as a PSU whose wattage rating is at least *m × n* where *m* is the motherboard's supply requirement and *n* is the number of motherboards you want to power; each rail has its own maximum amperage specification. You will find these specifications documented in the manual for any power supply worth buying. You *may* find the per-line requirements documented in the manual for the motherboard -- but I doubt it.)
- Buy that PSU and modify it so that it can connect to as many motherboards as you want it to run. This involves opening the PSU housing and soldering in additional wire harnesses -- that is to say, this involves exposing yourself to significant risk of electrocution, and also relying on your ability to solder well enough to avoid creating either a risk of destroying the motherboards to which the PSU will be connected, or a risk of fire greater than that involved in the use of a cheap power supply.

tl;dr It's possible in theory, but the odds of getting it to work in practice are quite long, and the odds of getting it to work *safely* rather longer. You're far better off running one power supply per motherboard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I use this for example: http://www.moddiy.com/product_images/m/501/T1TLyqXkJkXXasw_wS_010244__20079_zoom.jpg

Comment: @SkyRipper That will solve the second point, but not the first one - you'll still need a PSU capable of supplying enough power to two MoBos. Even if such PSUs exist, they will probably too expensive to consider if you're building a cheap system.

Comment: I see your point but I don't understand you exactly; if I have a 800watt psu and power two motherboards with only 100watt each, won't it work?

Comment: @SkyRipper - Its just not about giving the motherboard enough power its the fact each motherboard at any point in time would required DIFFERENT amounts of power.  So you would have to build the power supply with that capability, which serves no purpose, because you could simply purchase two seperate power supplies instead.